# Banker's Algorithm Issue : Can a process request resources more than it's need?

Tags: operating-system, deadlock, bankers-algorithm

[In the problem mentioned in the image, on request of p3 (0,2,0) the need of p3 is becoming negative(means it has an extra resource). According to other general rules the request can be granted since safe sequence exists : P1 -> P3 -> P2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrV5A.jpg)

Can it is possible for a process to request more resources then it's need in Banker Algorithm ?
Does such request will considered valid or feasible, if safe sequence exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a process cannot be allowed to request more that its declared maximum need.

Reason: The Banker's algorithm uses the max need of each process while determining safety of a request.
If a process is allowed to request more than max need resources, then paths that were considered to be
safe during some previous allocations might become unsafe. So the safety analysis would collapse.

P.S. This answer is given by **Dhananjay Dhamdhere** https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~dmd/

Thanks sir, for resolving my query.